# How to manually upgrade a package?

Tags: apt

I'm trying to build a repository under Ubuntu 16.04 using autotools. However, whenever I try to build it, I get the following error:

```
autopoint: *** The AM_GNU_GETTEXT_VERSION declaration in your configure.ac
               file requires the infrastructure from gettext-0.19.8 but this version
               is older. Please upgrade to gettext-0.19.8 or newer.
```

In fact, the 'gettext' I have installed is older, but I can't upgrade it via an apt install.

```
gettext is already the newest version (0.19.7-2ubuntu3).
```

I have downloaded the newer gettext version source code from here: https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/gettext/ and built it. However, when I manually build the source code, the binaries are installed under usr/local/ and I don't know how to properly "replace" the old binaries by the newer ones.

I have tried a bunch of things, but I can't solve my problem. Could someone tell me the right way to go?

Thanks

@Update: I downloaded the package manually from https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/amd64/gettext/download and installed it. Now apt says:

```
gettext is already the newest version (0.19.8.1-1ubuntu2).
```

which is already a supported version. However, I keep getting exactly the same error

Comment: Have you run apt-get update before apt-get upgrade? Did you originally install from a single-version repository? If so I would try purging the program and reinstalling from either an updated repository or the general.